# Crystal Report not loading sometimes

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

[image]

We have tried same dataset several times. Stored procedure returns same rowset. Sometimes it loads, sometimes it doesn't. There is no pattern we can find.

Comment: So if you can't found error pattern, while having access to all source code and environment, how can we help you just using an error message?

Comment: I was hoping if there is anyone facing the same error message and solve it. This report is running for over 5 years and never showing any error like this before.